# Call a method from Service in Domain Class Grails 2.2.2

Tags: grails

I have a domain class called Test. I want to call a method from its service TestService in the  domain class.
What is the right way to call in grails 2.2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
def testService
```

to the top of your domain class, and call:

```
testService.method()
```

Where you want to call it